# SQL: Using Max function and returning max per client, not overall

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new to using SQL and I am attempting to build my first query/report, and was hoping I could get some help on this (this seems to be the place to be for that!). Basically what I want to create is a report that shows when the last time an employee or contractor was paid. We have a database with all this information, I just want to return a distinct list of every person with their last pay date. What I end up getting is either a list of every pay we have made (Person1 is on the list 20+ times with each pay date), or a list with every person and the most recent paydate of anyone, not just that person. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT  table1.Office ,
    table1.EE_No ,
    table1.Name ,
    table1.Code ,
    table1.Freq ,
    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                MAX(table2.PayDate)
      FROM      table2
    ) AS Last_Paycheck
FROM    table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.UniqueID = table2.UniqueID
WHERE   table1.EndDate IS NULL
```

What this returns is a list of every employee with 8/30/2013 listed, which is the last time anyone has got paid, but not everyone. What am I doing wrong here with the Max function? I've tried a lot of different ways and no luck, must be missing something obvious here!

Comment: Do you really name your tables this way, `table1` and `table2`?

Comment: No, I replaced their names with table1 and table2 for confidentiality purposes. I am definitely a SQL noob but not that bad. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try something like

```
Select table1.Office, 
table1.EE_No, 
table1.Name, 
table1.Code, 
table1.Freq, 
(Select distinct MAX (table2.PayDate) 
from table2
where table1.UniqueID = table2.UniqueID
) as Last_Paycheck

from
table1 on 
where 
table1.EndDate is null
```

The other way would be something like

```
Select table1.Office, 
table1.EE_No, 
table1.Name, 
table1.Code, 
table1.Freq, 
MAX (table2.PayDate) as Last_Paycheck

from
table1 inner join
table2
on table1.UniqueID = table2.UniqueID
where 
table1.EndDate is null
GROUP BY table1.Office, 
table1.EE_No, 
table1.Name, 
table1.Code, 
table1.Freq
```

Also note as the comment states, use more descriptive table names, as this will greatly improve maitainability later.

Comment: Both of these methods work as well for what I am trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
(Select distinct MAX (table2.PayDate) from table2) as Last_Paycheck
```

To something like this:

```
MAX (table2.PayDate) OVER (PARTITON BY table2.UniqueID) as Last_Paycheck
```

With no `Select` needed - You've already stated the association needed in your join clause.

Hope this does the trick...

Answer (score 0):

Use grouping:

```
Select table1.Office, 
table1.EE_No, 
table1.Name, 
table1.Code, 
table1.Freq, 
MAX (table2.PayDate) as Last_Paycheck
from table1 
inner join table2
on table1.UniqueID = table2.UniqueID
where table1.EndDate is null
group by table1.Office, 
table1.EE_No, 
table1.Name, 
table1.Code, 
table1.Freq
```

Comment: Works great, thanks!! I'll definitely do some more research on grouping.